# Conditional Formatting Based on another Cell with Multiple IF's

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

**I had** a Conditional Format in Place, but it somehow stopped working once I filled in an `IF` Argument into my cell.

`A1` Contains a Number I put in manually
`A2` Contains another Number I put in manually
`A3` Contains a Number which changes (with `IF` Arguments) depending on which number is input into `A1`

`A3` Is supposed to change it's color depending on the Number it contains.

My Argument for `A3` is

```
=IF(A1=1, "3", IF(A1=2, "6", IF(A1=3, "3", if(A1=4, "6","N/A"))))
```

I had my Conditional Format on Cell `A3` as `"Custom Formula is"` with the Formula being

```
=A2=A3 -> Green
```

and a second one as

```
=A2<A3 -> Red
```

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You turned your numbers into text by putting quotes around them. Take the quotes off the numbers in your formula, and your CF should work again:

```
=IF(A1=1, 3, IF(A1=2, 6, IF(A1=3, 3, IF(A1=4, 6,"N/A"))))
```